# Weird outputs from SendMessage on 64-bit Windows

Tags: windows, user-interface, message

I'm sort of new to Windows GUI programming.
I got some code which works fine on 32-bit Windows but go weird on 64-bit Win7 (same exe).

```
LWG_CEDIT_GET( m_hwnd, IDC_EDIT_NUM_TEST, g_tmp_str, 4096 );
```

where LWG_CEDIT_GET is defined as:

```
#define LWG_CEDIT_GET(h,id,v,m) \
((*((U32*)(v))=(m)),SendMessage(GetDlgItem((h),(id)),EM_GETLINE,0,(LPARAM)(char*)(v))
```

On WinXP 32, this gives me `g_tmp_str="1"` (of course I inputted '1' into the textfield in dialog). But, on Win7 64, this gives me `g_tmp_str=""`(Oops, the weird character can't be shown in stackoverflow, whatever, odd char. [0]=49'1' [1]=16'').

Generally speaking, 32bit exe program can work flawlessly on Win7 64, so, why my program failed? Thanks.

**Edit 1**: IsWindowsUnicode(m_hwnd) returns FALSE.

Comment: I compiled only once on 32-bit platform. I ran this 32-bit exe on both 32 and 64 bit win.

Comment: (Deleted my previous answer/comments as I misunderstood things. I forgot how awful the edit control and EM_GETLINE in particular are. :) ) New question: What window are you pointing this at? Is it your own window or one in another process? Is the target window unicode or ansi?

Comment: Thanks, it's the window of my process. The program is a simple one process one thread program. How can I tell the 'unicode' or 'ansi' question?

Comment: You can use IsWindowUnicode to detect if a window is unicode or ansi. It's probably not that if it is your own code, though, since it shouldn't be switching unless you change how it's created. Maybe someone else can spot the problem, but if not it might be worth creating a very simple test app to see if the problem happens with that and, if it does, post the source for people to play with it. Sorry I can't think of an obvious answer. :(

Comment: Thanks anyway, :) I learned the `IsWindowUnicode`. And I'll try to create a minimal testcase for it.

Comment: Ok, I asked msdn and got useful feedback. It's a "null terminater" problem. Closing this question. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761584.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my last comments of the topic.